# Beginner Python: How to give different responses to ELSE in a while-loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, I'm working my way through Learn Python the Hard Way, and I am on Lesson 36, where I make my own BBS-text-style game based on the one he did in lesson 35.

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex36.html

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex35.html

So, I did a decent job, but I noticed that when I mimicked his eternal while-loop, where the player can't ever leave the room under anything but very specific circumstances, the loop always gives the same response for the else...unless they say the right thing, they're stuck forever.

Here's my code:

```
def sleeping_giant():
    print "There is a single door, with a giant sleeping in front of it."
    print "How can you get the giant to move?"
    print "Should you wake him?"
    giant_moved = False

    while True:
        choice = raw_input("> ")

        if choice == "Yes":
            dead("The giant rips you into four pieces and uses your quartered body as a      stack of pillows.")
        elif choice == "No" and not giant_moved: 
            print "The giant rolls in his sleep, clearing an easy path to the door."
            giant_moved = True 
        elif "Open" or "Go" in choice and giant_moved:
            treasure_room()
        else:
            print "I have no idea what the fuck you are trying to say to me.  English.     Do you speak it?!"
```

Apologies if that format doesn't translate well.

Anyway, anytime the user types something that doesn't satisfy an if or an elif, they will receive that same else response.

How would I change this?  As in, make it more dynamic, so that if they keep screwing up the response, the else response changes?

I can't figure out how to get the code to say (in non-literal terms, I mean, I can't get the logic to say), 'If the else has been used, the response should be a new else, and once that one has been used, it should be yet another else response'.

If this doesn't make sense, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the incremental version of Greg's answer using a counter so you can get a predictable order of responses:

```
global responses = [ "Nice try. Try again.",
        "Sorry, what was that?",
        "I don't know what that means."]
def sleeping_giant():
   counter = 0
   print "There is a single door, with a giant sleeping in front of it."
   print "How can you get the giant to move?"
   print "Should you wake him?"
   giant_moved = False

   while True:
       choice = raw_input("> ")

       if choice == "Yes":
           dead("The giant rips you into four pieces and uses your quartered body as a      stack of pillows.")
       elif choice == "No" and not giant_moved: 
           print "The giant rolls in his sleep, clearing an easy path to the door."
           giant_moved = True 
       elif ("Open" in choice or "Go" in choice) and giant_moved:
           treasure_room()
       else:
           print responses[counter]
           if counter < 2:
              counter += 1
```

Comment: To all who visit, I picked this answer because it allowed for a specific order of responses, rather than just random response.

Answer (score 3):

This condition:

```
    elif "Open" or "Go" in choice and giant_moved:
```

parses as the following (according to [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)):

```
    elif "Open" or (("Go" in choice) and giant_moved):
```

Since `"Open"` is considered True, this condition will always match. It sounds like you might instead want:

```
    elif ("Open" in choice or "Go" in choice) and giant_moved:
```

To choose a different response, try something like:

```
    else:
        responses = [
            "Nice try. Try again.",
            "Sorry, what was that?",
            "I don't know what that means.",
        ]
        print random.choice(responses)
```

Comment: I've added an example of a random response, hopefully that helps.

Comment: That looks like it will work just fine.  I'm gonna leave this open for the evening, just to see if any other suggestions materialize, but that seems to solve it.

Thank you!